# How do I insert a separator when concatenating a string in C#?

Tags: c#, list, concatenation, string-concatenation

I have a list of strings and I am concatenating it to flatten out the list by using the method seen here on DotNetPerls, http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-concat

My question is...in their List example where their output is "catdogperls" (see toward the bottom of the webpage, just before the Summary) how do I insert a # sign as a separator between "catdogperls" such that it becomes "cat#dog#perls"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this case you don't want to use `string.Concat()`, you want to [use `string.Join()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx).  This accepts a separator and an array of strings to join by that separator.  For example:

```
var joined = string.Join("#", theArray);
```

This would place the string value in `joined`:

```
"cat#dog#perls"
```

(assuming, of course, that `theArray` contains those values)

Comment: Thanks, I found your response most helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Try like this :

```
String.Join("#", catdogperls)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `String.Join()`, which takes a collection and a separator.

Answer (score 0):

Use [string.Join()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), it allows you to specify the separator you want between each string - it's been in the framework since v2.0.

In later versions of the framework it was extended so that you could pass in an IEnumerable instead of just an array.