# C# split string on a separator then remove an element and then join again by using a separator

Tags: c#, string, split

I have a string like `"SS\u001ffsdf\u001fA123456\u001f"`.

I am using below code to split the string,

`var record = _recordSection.Split("\u001f");`

I get a string array-like `"SS"`, `"ffsdf"`, and `"A123456"`.

I want to delete `"A123456"` and then again format the string like

`"SS\u001ffsdf\u001f\u001f"` How should I go about this?

Comment: How do you know that's the element you want to remove? Is it because it's the third element, it has the value `"A123456"`, or some other criterion? If you can answer that, you might be able to figure it out for yourself.

Comment: "split string on a separator then remove an element and then join again by using a separator" seem to be exactly what you want to do... What part is a problem? Definigely not https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+remove+element+array... I doubt if combining back is a problem either - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19624855/how-do-i-insert-a-separator-when-concatenating-a-string-in-c

Comment: Would `_recordSection = _recordSection.Replace("A123456", "");` work?

Comment: @madreflection sry, it's always going to be the third element.

Comment: Look up `string.Join` - it's kinda-sorta the opposite of `string.Split`.  You aren't really *removing* `"A123456"`, you are *replacing* it with `string.Empty` (or `""`) though.  I think @madreflection's point is the hardest part; how do you know which bit to remove?

Comment: @Flydog57 someone found the question very clear and useful - they will possibly edit that explanation in - no need to ask OP...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove the element `A123456`, a `.Select()` and a ternary operator will be enough.

```
string _recordSection = "SS\u001ffsdf\u001fA123456\u001f";
var record = _recordSection.Split('\u001f');
var merged = string.Join("\u001f", record.Select(x => x != "A123456" ? x : string.Empty));
```

If you want to remove the *third* element it is even easier:

```
string _recordSection = "SS\u001ffsdf\u001fA123456\u001f";
var record = _recordSection.Split('\u001f');
record[2] = string.Empty;
var merged = string.Join("\u001f", record);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you said, you need to delete third element - you can use xanato's solution or this :

```
int positionToRemove = 3;
string separator = "\u001f";
string _recordSection = "SS\u001ffsdf\u001fA123456\u001f";

var recordList = _recordSection.Split(separator).ToList();
recordList.Remove(recordList[positionToRemove - 1]);
var result = string.Join(separator, recordList);

Console.WriteLine(result); //will output "SS\u001ffsdf\u001f\u001f"
```

Answer (score 0):

All nice solutions, but using `string.Split` can be inefficient on large strings.

If you need the last element to be removed, you can calculate the substring size by doing this:

```
var record = _recordSection.Substring(
    0,
    _recordSection.LastIndexOf('\u001f', _recordSection.Length - 2)) + "\u001f\u001f";
```

The same can be done going from the beginning with consecutive `IndexOf` calls.

No-one seems to have pointed out that `\u001f` is a single escaped `char`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private const string InitialString = "SS\u001ffsdf\u001fA123456\u001f";
private const char Separator = '\u001f';
```

and then just split, replace the third item and join things back:

```
var splitStrings = InitialString.Split(Separator);
splitStrings[2] = string.Empty;
var result = string.Join(Separator.ToString(), splitStrings);
```

When finished, `result` looks like (copied from debugger):

```
"SS\u001ffsdf\u001f\u001f"
```

If you want "the last item" instead of the third, use `splitStrings.Length-1` as the index instead of `2`.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't need to be more complicated than:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace HandyExtensions
{
    static class StringExtensions
    {
        static string Splice(this string s, string separator, Func<string, int, bool> desired ) {
            string[] segments = s.Split(separator)
                                 .Where( desired )
                                 .ToArray()
                                 ;
            return String.Join(separator, segments);
        }
    }
}
```

That should let you say things like

```
"a,b,c,d,e,f,g".Splice(",", (s,i) => i % 2 == 0 )
```

and get back `"a,c,e,g"`